# Running different files in the same project on CLion

Tags: c, duplicates, clion, file-management

I'm currently doing some exercises to learn C on CLion but i have noticed that if i create multiple files, when i run the program i can't select from which file so the compiler tries with the whole project. But obviously it gives me back an error because in each of these file i've used the 'main' function. So i'm looking for a way to run a single file inside a project with multiple ones.

By looking around i found out that i can create a 'Run/Debug configuration' for each file, and when i select that i can run the single file. But that's not very comfortable to do each time and i'm not sure if this function is meant to be used like this. (i have already Adjusted the CMakeFile to make the new files executable)

P.S. My level is beginner on C and i just joined a CS science course at the university, so if there are easier IDEs to someone like me please tell me(already used XCode, VScode and CodeBlocks, and at my level they look the same).

thanks.

Comment: By now, forget about files, it's just an organized way. You coud write everything in a single file. Each app can have only one "main" function. If you need to test other functions, where ever they are, call them from main or other func. And set a "break point" inside that function so as to the debugger can stop there and show you vars.

Comment: You said i could do everything pn a single file. But here i got another problem: on CLion i can't create a single file, so i tried on Xcode and there i can but i can't run or debug it. Any advice?

Comment: *"can't create a single file*" Man, first time I hear something like that about any IDE. It's true that some IDEs need a separated file for project-configuration. But I'm 100% sure you can distribute your code in one or several files.

Comment: Ok. Then i probably missed it. Thanks